# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'followTo' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to adapt this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1/

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);

    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#product_right').followTo(250);
```

to my website: http://www.victoriarockera.com/shop/ropa-chica/soy-yo-979.html

but for any reason, I'm receiving this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'followTo' of undefined

and it is not working...

why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: of course @kruga, as you can check on the code

Comment: Try using `jQuery.prototype` instead of `$.fn`

Comment: Thanks @kruga; now the error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'followTo' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `('#product_right').followTo(250);` is not triggered within your website. Try to add the following code to your site:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    ('#product_right').followTo(250);
});
```

That could also explain why it works within JSFiddle and not on your website. You might try that.

Comment: I'm having some confict with JQuery because now I get: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function. Thanks @Rotan075

Comment: Yep! that is definitely a jQuery source problem. That should also explain why the value is undefined. I would also (for testing purposes) check if the value is passed correctly to the function by adding a console.log like: `console.log(pos)`

Comment: Besides that I also see that you load multiple jquery version files in your website. Try to avoid that. Use only 1 jQuery version to prevent conflicting code ;) @superTramp